# How to remove and replace first character of a string

Tags: java, android

I have a String coming from EditText that have `0` as first character

How i can change `0` with a specific String `"+22"`

for example if String is  "0911-111-1111"  then it should be  "+22911-111-1111"

```
btn_request_sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            phone = inputPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            if (phone.length() == 13)
            {
                if (phone.startsWith("0")) {

                // here how to split string

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile number is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile length is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are getting it as string. Take `substring` and if is equal to 0 remove and add +22

Comment: Try: `if (s.startsWith("0")) s = "+22" + s.substring(1);` --- Or: `s = s.replaceFirst("^0", "+22");`

Comment: @Andreas well i've updated question, this is how i'm getting phone i've used `String. phone` then i've used length to make sure it's right number and start with 09 because i want them to input with 09 but change it to +22. now where i shoud input data? can u answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy,
you will get text in string so you can do like

```
  btn_request_sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            phone = inputPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            if (phone.length() == 13) {
                if (phone.startsWith("09")) {
                    phone = "+22" + phone.substring(1, phone.length());
                    runVerification(phone);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile number is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile length is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `charAt(0)` will fail if `your_number` is an empty string. Safer to use `startsWith("0")`. --- `your_number.substring(1, your_number.length())` can be shortened to `your_number.substring(1)`.

Comment: if your_number is null then it will also fail for startsWith("0"). there is nothing safe..we have to make sure that string is not null and empty @Andreas

Comment: If string comes from a TextBox, it cannot be null, but it *can* be an empty string, when user hits submit without typing anything.

Comment: but what's wrong if someone just check that string is not empty..and also in case of phone number most developer put validations..like phone number must be at least 10 digit etc else it's already invalid and useless

Comment: to be honest this thing completely depends on developer. it's not like we are getting a context in fragment  where it can be null if activity not attached @Andreas

Comment: @AshwiniViolet well i've updated question, this is how i'm getting phone i've used String. phone then i've used length to make sure it's right number and start with 09 because i want them to input with 09 but change it to +22. now where i shoud input data?

Comment: i changed my answer according your question..check now if it help @MohammadEskandari

Comment: is this change 09 to +22 or just 0? because i only want to change 0.

Comment: Use exceptions for user input handling

Comment: it will change 0 to +22..you should run it and check by yourself  @MohammadEskandari

Comment: oh so base on that (1, ...) it will change first digit right?

Comment: yes and also you can user just simple phone.substring(1); it's also same as Andreas suggested @MohammadEskandari

Comment: Thanks mate, if i asked at top it wasn't because i wanted to make sure, i wanted to learn it. Thanks anyway. and dono what these downvotes are about...